# A math newcommand as name in newglossaryentry

Tags: macros, glossaries

How to get a math expression defined with newcommand as a {name} in `\newglossaryentry`?
I have this

```
\newcommand{\equivdef}{{\overset{\text{def}}{\equiv\joinrel\equiv}}}
```

and want this glossary entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{equivdefi}{name={$\equivdef$},
description={define as equivalent to}
}
```

But get the error:

```
"! Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
 <inserted text>
 \par
 l.10 }"
```

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[ebook,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[sort=use,toc,style=long3col]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\equivdef}{{\overset{\text{def}}{\equiv\joinrel\equiv}}}

\newglossaryentry{equivdefi}{name={$\equivdef$},
description={define as equivalent to}
}

\makeglossaries
\normalfont
\begin{document}
Use symbol \gls{equivdefi} and define $p\veebar q$ as
\begin{equation}
p\veebar q\equivdef (p\vee q)\wedge\bigl(\neg(p\wedge q)\bigr).
\end{equation}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The entry prints in the Glossary but not in the text.
[image: Mising symbol]

[image: Symbol in entry]

Comment: in your text you say you have `\newcommand{\equivdef}` but your example shows `\newcommand{\equivdefi}{` leaving `equivdef` undefined

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea to use a math content macro as a glossary key name

Comment: Agree @ChristianHupfer, but I would like to have it. In this example the entry prints in the Glossary but not in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't neglect the error messages you get during processing. In this case the error is one that points to a fragile command in a moving argument:

```
! Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 }
```

Solution: add `\protect`.

```
\documentclass[ebook,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[sort=use,toc,style=long3col]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\equivdef}{{\overset{\text{def}}{\equiv\joinrel\equiv}}}

\newglossaryentry{equivdefi}{
  name={$\protect\equivdef$},% <---- \protect
  description={define as equivalent to},
}

\makeglossaries
\normalfont
\begin{document}
Use symbol \gls{equivdefi} and define $p\veebar q$ as
\begin{equation}
p\veebar q\equivdef (p\vee q)\wedge\bigl(\neg(p\wedge q)\bigr).
\end{equation}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, your definition of `\equivdef` has a wrong pair of braces; moreover, you want `\textnormal` rather than `\text` (try it in a theorem statement to see why.

```
\newcommand{\equivdef}{\overset{\textnormal{def}}{\equiv\joinrel\equiv}}
```

[image]

Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Yes @egreg, with `\textnormal` you avoid the slanted or italics in a theorem. I can't see where to `\protect` the command. I use PDFLaTeX in TeXmaker.

Comment: @tatojo Sorry, I missed adding it.

Comment: Great answer @egreg, this `\protect` command was something new for me.